# Populate a combobox in a datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, entity-framework-mapping

I have a WPF Datagrid populated with data from one SQL table using Entity Framework, is it possible to populate a combobox in the same Datagrid using data from a different table.

I have this code working

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="reasonColumn" Header="Reason" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="Supplier Quantity"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="Supplier Price"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="Supplier Numbers"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="Supplier Codes"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="Branch Quantity"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="Branch Numbers"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="Branch Codes"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="IM Numbers"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="Pop Prices"/>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But I would prefer it to be dynamically populated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply bind your `ComboBox.ItemsSource` to wherever your collection is

For example, this will bind a collection from your DataGrid's DataContext:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.MyComboBoxList, 
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
```

As another example, this will bind to a static class containing your collection

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding 
          Source={x:Static local:MyStaticClass.MyComboBoxList}" />
```

Comment: Is it possible when the grid is populated using a CollectionViewSource?

Comment: @Wellie Both examples shown are bound to collections that are unrelated to the actual grid's source. The 1st example binds to `DataGrid.DataContext.MyComboBoxList`, so you can set `myDataGrid.DataContext = SomeClass`, and have a property on `SomeClass` called `MyComboBoxList`. The 2nd example binds to a `static` class in your project called `MyStaticClass`, which also would contain a property called `MyComboBoxList`